# What is the speed of a standard UIScrollView animation (px/s)

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiscrollview, core-animation

I added a `UIPageControl` to a `UIScrollView` and want to enable page changes based on interactivity with the control.

I am updating the page control's `currentPage` property in my `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method. Unfortunately, I have to disable this feature when scrolling programmatically because it makes the page control blink on and off. (Am I approaching this incorrectly?)

Since UIScrollView doesn't have a `setContentOffset: animated:` with a completion callback I need to emulate its speed with a UIView animation. Is the speed defined somewhere or should I just measure it?

How do I figure out what my duration should be to make the animation exactly match `[(UIScrollView) setContentOffset:x animated:YES]`'s speed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're needed but have you looked into scrollRectToVisible ?

If you want to go to page 2 :

```
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480) animated:YES];
```

My viewDidScroll looks like this, i don't have any blinking

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Comment: Basically I want to discover what the animation time is on that method. I think I need callback after it finishes animating. My `scrollViewDidScroll` updates the pageControl in a functionally identical manner and if I tap the right side of the page control it darkens, lightens, and then darkens again as the animation completes. (vs. if I tap a button to go to the right, or slide the scroll view with my thumb it animates precisely correctly)

Comment: Well the speed varies, i believe it's more like 0.3 second for every animation but that could change, so i'm not sure that is how you want to do it. I don't understand what else you are trying to animate, neither why you need a callback.